# "Include" a Class in C#

Tags: c#, class

This is a bit of a newbie question about C#. I'm using Windows Forms with Visual Studio 2008.

So, I am able to create a class with static variables and functions. For example:

```
namespace foo
{
    public class bar
    {
         const static int money = 5;

         public static int FuncX()
         {
              return 6;
         }
    }
}
```

Then, over in my form, I have a label, and I can go:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = bar.money.ToString();
        label1.Text = bar.FuncX().ToString();
    }
```

My question is whether or not I could, say, call FuncX without needing the bar. in front of it? I know in C++ if you include a header file with a function in it, you can call it without the need for a prefix, so I was wondering if C# had something similar.

Comment: No, it doesn't. However, C# 6 will _hopefully_ have _static imports_ much like Java.. and as you've described here.

Comment: C# doesn't have static imports. That in mind - the way you are using static here is very dangerous for at least two reasons (1) it isn't object oriented and (2) static is much like a "global" which ends up translating to not being thread safe. I recommend reading more about OOP in order to take full advantage of C#

Comment: Just because something is not object oriented does not mean it's necessarily *very dangerous*.

Comment: I don't understand why I should hope that C# 6 will implement this this 'feature'. What is its advantage other than confusing everything?

Comment: @Steve, yeah. There could be a hell lot of ambiguity if that was implemented ;)

Comment: I must admit that I have not looked into the matter, but, as is, it doesn't seem an advantage.

Comment: It is possible in ASPX.NET, you can include anything to be part of your .aspx file, a method can be part of the include too. However, I definitely won't recommend doing it!

Comment: C++ doesn't have that either. What it does have is that you can define functions outside classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is nothing of that sort *now*. C# 6 however will bring this future hopefully as Simon Whitehead. For example after importing `Console` using some magic syntax, you can just use `WriteLine()` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`. But not now.

For now, only namespaces can be imported using an `using` statement, which will give you access to all (*please don't argue about access modifiers lol*) the classes or whatever inside that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can not include/alias static methods or fields from other types so that you can use them without specifying the type in c#. All there is is the using directive to rename types and there are extension methods. Extension methods are static methods disguised as instance methods of other types.

If you really don't want the type name in front of it, you'll have to write a wrapper method.